# Make custom Java object by passing comma separated list of properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I’m trying to find a solution to make a customisable excel export from a list of objects.

Problem statement:
I have a bunch of projects which needs to generate an excel report. The report is generated on top of a list of specific Java object (jpa entity). Now, I wanted to make the columns configurable so that each project can have a specific set of columns in their reports. Which means I should be able to make child objects dynamically based on an ever changing list of columns.

My potential solution:
If every project can handover a list of columns in comma separated form (via properties file) and I could somehow dynamically create sub objects based on this list. For that i need a function which takes in this list and give me sub objects. However i’m not able to figure out how.

If someone has a better solution for my problem, I’d be greatful if you could share it.

Comment: Why don't you keep report as json in clob?

Comment: If you could share some code snippets that would help people better understand what you are trying to go for.

Comment: If you want to create "sub-objects" where there can be more than one type of sub-object, that's not possible.  Java serialization embeds type information in its stream so that it can recreate the objects.  Without type information, you can't guess the correct type.  This is actually a big problem with JSON too that its only type is "associative array" and anything more detailed just isn't possible unless you feed it unambiguous type information.

Comment: Does it need to be a full java object? Or could you just return a map, with keys based on the columns?

Comment: @Gagravarr a map would also be okay.

Comment: Have your method return eg `List<Map<String,Object>>`. Read the first row, saving what each column's heading is, eg `Map<Integer,String>` for column number to heading. Finally, read each row, new map, iterate over cells, where there is data lookup the heading then store?